# Export list of numbers as one line to a text file

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I have the following list:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Now I would like to export the list to a text file such that the numbers are all on one line separated by a tab:

> 1 2 3 4 5

When I do:

```
Export["list.txt",list]
```

I get:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

I am wondering if it is possible to get the desired output ?

Comment: `Export["list.txt", list, "Table", "LineSeparators" -> " "]`?

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer, then I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Export["list.txt", list, "Table", "LineSeparators" -> " "]
```

The `"Table"` format also supports a `"FieldSeparators"` option to separate columns in 2D data, should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

My take on it:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}

Export["list.txt", list, "TSV"]
```

In TSV values in the same row are delimited by tab and values in the same column are delimited by newline.